# Using ACF on Posts Page

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use ACF Pro to code a headline/page description on a Wordpress page, but it just keeps showing 'Array' in place of the headline/description.

I know about the `<?php the_field('XYZ', get_option('page_for_posts')); ?>`, but that hasn't seemed to work for me. I've tried everything, but I'm at a loss- how can I make it work?

HTML/PHP CODE:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Blog Page Template */ ?>

<?php get_header()   ?>

<body>
<!--------------- Blog Intro -------------------->
<?php the_field('blog_introduction', get_option('page_for_posts')); ?>
    <div id="introParagraph" class=" col-xs-12 p-y-2">
        <?php
            if (have_rows('blog_introduction')):while(have_rows('blog_introduction')):the_row();
        ?>
        <h1 class="text-xs-left col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1 m-b-1">
            <?php
                the_sub_field('page_header'); ?>
        </h1>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-7 m-t-1">
            <h3 class="text-xs-left" id="headerDescription">
                <?php
                    the_sub_field('page_description_paragraph'); ?>
            </h3>
        </div>

        <?php   endwhile;
        else :
            // no rows found
        endif;
        ?>
    </div>
```

However, when I put that, it shows up like [this](https://i.imgur.com/rxqM0AD.png), when it should like this [this](https://i.imgur.com/UM0fZQn.png).

Comment: What type of field is it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a static page as your blog home page? You can do this under [Settings > Reading](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen). Otherwise `get_option('page_for_posts')` won't work.